# What does slot-scope mean in the Vuetify.js v-hover guide?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I was trying to get v-hover to work and the guide writes:

> either the value prop should be set to `true` or the wrapped element should contain `slot-scope="{ wrapper }"`.

In all the examples `v-slot="{hover}"` is used and `slot-scope={wrapper}` does not work meaning that the `wrapper` value does not change.
The guide page: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/hover/

Comment: Doesn't work ? have you tried it on your code and it didn't or just because they didn't use it on their examples?

Comment: @AbdelillahAissani As I stated the `wrapper` value does not change. So when used in a `v-if` directive the element never appears.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find `slot-scope` in the guide page you have linked. Maybe it has been removed from the code but the docu wasn't already updated.

The default way to use `v-hover` is to use the slot `v-slot="{ hover }"`. You get a "local variable" named `hover` that you can use inside the `<v-hover>` tags:

```html
<v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
  <div>
    <div v-if="hover">Hovering!</div>
    <div v-else>Hover over me!</div>
  </div>
</v-hover>
```

If you want to use the hover state outside the `<v-hover>` tags or in the script part, use `v-model` instead of `v-slot` (this is what I searched when I found this question). The variable used in `v-model` has to be defined in `data`:

```html
The DIV below is {{ hover ? '' : 'not' }} being hovered.
<v-hover v-model="hover">
  <div>
    <div v-if="hover">Hovering!</div>
    <div v-else>Hover over me!</div>
  </div>
</v-hover>
```

```js
data(){
  return {
    hover: false,
  }
},
watch: {
  hover(val) {
    console.log('Hover:', val)
  },
},
```

I have made a codepen where you can see the different approaches in action: https://codepen.io/sebu10n/pen/bGMLEQB

Comment: The question was asked on 11th of Jan 2011. Since that time, the documentation has changed, because the slot syntax has changed in Vue. At that time the syntax was `slot-scope="{ hover }"`. Now it's `v-slot="{ hover }"`. The scope is the object that is typically deconstructed and contains exposed data from the child scope that can be used in the slot template, inside the parent. In this case, the scope has the following signature: `{ hover: Boolean }`.

Comment: Also, *"The variable used in `v-model` has to be defined in `data`"* is simply not true. It can also be a computed getter/setter. That's what you use when you want to place a `prop` in `v-model`. In the getter you return the prop and in the setter you emit the update event. And in composition API it can also be any reactive reference, returned by `setup`.